# Rescaling NDVI from 0-255 to -1-1 in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: spatial-analyst, arcgis-pro, raster-calculator, ndvi

My NDVI raster ranges from 0-255. My goal is to get values from -1 to 1.

If using the Raster Calculator, what would be the correct equation to achieve this?

I'm working in ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: What have you tried/researched so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/929107/7144368

Comment: how about (old value*2/255)-1 ?